# Transparent Bitmap blocking mouse events for underlaying objects

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, mouseevent

I'm embedding a bitmap via the Embed tag. It's basically a circle shape with one thousand effects created by the graphic designer :)

Now my problem is that I have some icons around this circle, in its outer part, but the rectangular bounding box of the bitmap it's blocking any event. I cannot change the z-index of the icons because of my setup, and I'm really confused about this.

Obviously I already tried to wrap this loaded bitmap in an sprite and setting its mouseEnabled property to false (also its mouseChildren, just in case), but it doesn't work....

Do I really need to use getObjectsUnderThePoint method as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416629/forward-mouseevent-in-transparent-bitmap-to-underlying-movieclip) or am I missing something obvious?

I'm going to put apart my pride and ask for help :)
Thank you!

My display list contains two instances of two different classes:

- Submenu (where the icons are)
- Main Menu (where the bitmap is)

...that means that my icons holder instance is below the one containing the bitmap.

Comment: Bitmap should block any mouse events if it's not in the container. It doesn't receive any neither (and that's why it won't block any event if it's on its own) Maybe you should try to .mouseEnabled = false your Main Menu object

Comment: thx @KumoKairo, if you post it as an answer I would be glad to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bitmap shouldn't block any mouse events if it's not in the container. It doesn't receive any neither (and that's why it won't block any event if it's on its own) Maybe you should try to .mouseEnabled = false your Main Menu object

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need mouse interaction with bitmap, you can just wrap it with the `Sprite` and set the `mouseEnabled` flag for the wrapper sprite to `false`:

```
    var wrapper:Sprite = new Sprite();
    wrapper.addChild(bitmap);
    wrapper.mouseChildren = wrapper.mouseEnabled = false;
```

UPD: For future - any additional `Sprite` wrapper will block mouse, so you have to set `mouseEnabled=false` for all parent Sprites or set `mouseChildren=false` to the most top one.

Comment: thx but as stated in the question, I already tried it and it's not working, I don't know why.....

Comment: Ok, I missed it. So can you provide some code and display list structure of the issued part of your project?

Comment: I've added a little edit describing my display list, thank you

Comment: so you already have wrapper, it's a MainMenu and you can disable mouse for it, instead of creating another one wrapper. For future - any additional _Sprite_ wrapper will block mouse, so you have to set mouseEnabled false for all parent Sprites or set _mouseChildren=false_ to the most top one.